# Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within - Cucumber js

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, ui-automation, cucumberjs

I am using protractor with cucumber js
i have all function with async and await and also set global timeout

var {setDefaultTimeout} = require('cucumber');
setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);

```
Then('I click on tab', async ()=> {
  
    await organizationOperation.clickHeaderTab();

  });
```

Question - if i use wrong xpath/element is not located in UI, in that case getting below error

Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 60000 milliseconds

It should throw an error locator not found (locator text)

**or if directly i use**

```
  Then('I click on tab', async ()=> {
      
 const d = await $('.xxxxx').getText();
     console.log(d)

});
```

getting same error   -->  Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 30000 milliseconds

Why it is not showing - element not found error on console..?

Comment: add your clickHeaderTab function

Comment: async clickHeaderTab(){
        return await organizationComponent.clickHeaderTab();
    }

Comment: can you please provide more details of your issue? with more code snippets?

Comment: suppose this is simple example

Then('I click on tab', async ()=> {
      
 const d = await $('.xxxxx').getText();  // css path is not avail on UI 
     console.log(d)

});


In that case it should return element not found on console. but getting promise not resolves in 60000 mili sec.. like that

Answer (score 0):

Are you using implicit wait in your code while launching a browser? If Yes, make sure your timeout is more than implicit wait time you provided..
If not, declare implicit wait time with less than the default setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);

In case implicit wait is more than default time, we used to get this error function timed out, make sure to resolve with in ****. In case implicit wait is less than the default time, waiting for an element via implicit wait will expire first and throws Element Not Found exception.